# using Log4net and Activator.CreateInstance

Tags: c#, logging, log4net, activator, createinstance

I am using log4net to log my application,

I  have weird issue , I have some class that created dynamically using Activator.CreateInstance.

But for some reason that classes don’t write the log,

Any Idea why ?

Comment: Should it write to the log? Does it contain any logging statements at all?

Comment: sure , otherwise what the hell am I asking

Comment: Could you provide us with a small program that reproduce this problem?

Comment: Did you ever get a solution @MoShe? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: were you able to get a solution?  (9 year later, having same issue)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps Activator.CreateInstance() is choosing a different constructor for this class?  I've frequently had a problem where my class has two constructors, and I forgot to get one to call `: this(..)` and thus my initialization logic didn't get set.